# Initialising an array of objects from a CSV file

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

This problem takes a bit of explaining, I'll try to be as concise as possible:

I have am trying to initalise an array of Can objects, these objects only have 2 fields (both Strings): name, manufacturer

I am trying to initialise the fields by reading from a CSV file with the following format:

Tomatoes,Heinz

Legumes,Jerry

(no space between the lines, it's being formatted like that on this site for some reason)

The first string in each row is the value I want to be the name, the 2nd is the manufacturer.

So I've created a method to read each line of the CSV, which passes each line to a tokenizer method to extract single values:

```
private void readFile (String inFilename) {
    FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
    InputStreamReader rdr;
    BufferedReader bufRdr;
    int lineNum;
    String line;
        try {
            fileStrm = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
            rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
            lineNum = 0;
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            while {line != null) {
                lineNum++;
                processLine(line);  //passes line to tokenizer
                line = bufRdr.readLine();
                 }
            fileStrm.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            if (fileStrm != null) {
                try { fileStrm.close(); } catch (IOException ex2) { }
             }
             System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

The lines are passed to this tokenizer method:

```
private String processLine(String csvRow) {
    String thisToken = null;
    StringTokenizer strTok;
    strTok = new StringTokenizer(csvRow, ",");
        while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
            thisToken = strTok.nextToken();
        }
}
```

And that's where I get a bit stuck. To initialise my array I think I'd need a for loop, something like

```
for (int i=0; i<=array.length;i++)
    {
    array[i].name = readFile("filename.csv");
    array[i].manufacturer = readFile("filename.csv");
    }
```

But obviously this will not work. Can anyone suggest how I can go about this? I'd prefer to keep the code mostly intact and figure out a solution using the existing code.

Thanks

Comment: What is the result of running this code?? Are you getting any error??

Comment: The methods read and tokenize correctly, I'm just not sure how to loop my array to be inialised by these methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First thing: -**

You are calling `processLine(line);`, but are not returning the `token` read from this method.. So, the token obtained in this method in `engulped` there only.. So, you should return something from that method..

**Second:-**

```
array[i].name = readFile("filename.csv");
array[i].manufacturer = readFile("filename.csv");
```

In the above code, you are calling `readFile()` each time for the two attributes.. So, even if you return somthing, these two attributes will be initialized to same value.. Because each time you are starting reading file from scratch..

**Third thing: -**

In fact your above code will not compile.. Because you are assigning the value of `readFile()` (which is actually not returning anything) to array.. So give a return type to this method.. It would be `String`.. And returning the tokens read..

***EDIT: -** 
** I would suggest, you can use [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method of `String` class.. `Tokenizer is not needed here, for just`splitting`around a single`comma(,)`

Also, rather than using an array, you can use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), in which you can add your newly created `object` on the fly.. That way, you will not have to `fix the size` of array.. (And this is what you will want, as you don't know how much line you will have in your file right?)

**Here's what you can do: -**

- Call the method `readFile` from somewhere, probably `main()`

  ```
  readFile("filename.csv")
  ```
- In your `readFile()` method, you can iterate over file to create an `ArrayList` like this: -

  ```
  List<Can> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

      String[] wordRead = line.split(',');
      yourList.add(new Can(wordRead[0], wordRead[1]));
  }
  ```

I assume, `Can` is the name of your class as you stated in your problem..

Comment: Thanks, the for loop is not yet part of my code but was an attempt at showing my problem.

I need some kind of loop that calls these methods to initialise the array. I will investigate the split method, but that doesn't solve my problem - how to intialise the array.

I'll add a return for the token (I meant to do this but overlooked it).

Comment: @Dawson.. Actually you don't need to return any value from `readFile`.. You can just call that method once, and it will iterate over the filename you gave, and `create your ArrayList` there only..

Comment: @Rohit..I'm trying to picture how this will work, a for loop within readFile? How will I structure it so that both fields in my objects get initialised correctly?

Comment: I have a method to count the number of lines in the CSV file so I know the size of the array.

Comment: Then that is not a good code.. You are actually `iterating` over a file twice.. Once to count the number of lines, so that you can create an array.. And then to actually read file to initialize array.. You don't have to do this.. That's why `ArrayList` was added to Java.

Comment: Thanks Rohit! I think your loop will work for me. I've not used ArrayList before but will this work with a regular array also?

Comment: @Dawson.. No.. for regular array, you have to have a counter variable starting from 0. And each time you add any element in the array using : - `array[i]`, you need to increment the value of `i` to point to next position.. But `array` is not a very good alternative if you want your array to grow Dynamically..